# 'set' object is not subscriptable の解消方法

Tags: python

```py
days =['Mon', 'Tue','Wed']
fruits = {'apple','banana', 'orange'}
drinks =  ['coffee', 'tea','beer']

for i in range(len(days)):
    print(days[i], fruits[i], drinks[i])
```

上記のプログラムを実行すると、下記の様なエラーが出ます。
これの解決方法を教えていただけますでしょうか。

```
TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-bce501f58d34> in <module>
      4 
      5 for i in range(len(days)):
----> 6     print(days[i], fruits[i], drinks[i])
      7 

TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable
```

求めているのは、下記の表示をさせる事です。

```
Mon apple coffee
Tue banana tea
Wed orange beer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

おそらくTypoで `fruits = {'apple','banana', 'orange'}`がSetになっているからでしょう。

`fruits = ['apple','banana', 'orange']`というようにListにすれば希望の表示になるはずです。